# Redireccionar a 1er video de búsqueda en YouTube

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, youtube

Necesito poder redireccionar usando `C#` al primer video de YouTube de una búsqueda web personalizada.

Podemos redireccionar a los resultados de una búsqueda de YouTube con el siguiente link personalizable:

```
https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=MI+BUSQUEDA+PERSONALIZADA
```

Esto nos deja todos los videos que coincidan con nuestra búsqueda.
En C# quedaria algo asi:

```
    public void BuscarUrl(string urlNav) 

// urlNav = https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=MI+BUSQUEDA+PERSONALIZADA

            {
                Context context = Application.Context;
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionView, Android.Net.Uri.Parse(urlNav));
                intent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
                context.StartActivity(intent);
            }
```

**Pero lo que estoy tratando de lograr es encontrar una forma de redireccionar al 1er video de la búsqueda personalizada sin necesidad de que el cliente le de click de forma manual 2 veces, ya que SIEMPRE SIEMPRE se seleccionara el 1er video.**

Entonces, recapitulando, la idea es tener por ejemplo un `EditText/TextBox` donde al clickear un botón que sera el que desencadena el redireccionamiento, este nos lleve al 1er video de la búsqueda que resulte del texto en el EditText/TextBox.
O sea, que se hagan las dos acciones:

1. Buscar texto.
2. Seleccionar el 1er video de los resultados encontrados.

**El código de arriba lo que realiza es la 'Búsqueda del texto' (#1), me falta la parte de 'Seleccionar el 1er video' (#2).**

Ideas?

Comment: Si no darìa click en forma manual como se supone que redireccionarìa , cuando haces que acciòn?

Comment: Tienes razón. No me explique bien en esa parte. Lo que quise decir es que no tenga que hacer click dos veces, solo 1 vez y haga las dos acciones (Buscar texto y seleccionar 1er video de los resultados). Ya actualice el post con lo que considero sera mas claro.

Comment: ¿Por qué la etiqueta Python?

Comment: @KennyAli si tiene manera de obtener los resultados de búsqueda (*es decir, los enlaces*), llame al método `BuscarUrl` pasándole por parámetro el prime link que encuentre. En su código no muestra cómo es que está tratando los resultados de `https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=MI+BUSQUEDA+PERSONALIZADA`...